# Angular2 remove / prevent duplicate records in array

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I have a component that is subscribed to a `subject` which is returning employee records and putting them into an array.

```
importResults: ImportResults[] = [];

constructor(
    private _massEmpService: MassEmpService
) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribe to our subject that lets us know about the added employees
    this._massEmpService.importedData.subscribe(obj => {
        if (obj) {
            // Ensure that we have unique results in our imported data
            this.importResults.push(_.uniqBy(obj, 'QID'));
        }
    });
}
```

My issue is that each time my button is clicked and this subscription receives data, its pushing the new data along side what is already there instead of ONLY adding records that don't exist.

**Here is an example on a single record received (I entered one user name and clicked search)**

[image]

**Here is an example when I add one additional user, leaving the previous one in the search field.**

[image]

As you can see, the first array is the original search result. The second array contains the first employee AND the new employee.

My expected outcome here is that there is a single array with unique objects. This would mean there should be 2 records from my example since the first employee was searched two times, he shouldnt be pushed or included into the array since that object already exists.

Am i using this `lodash` function incorrectly? `QID` is a unique valid key in the object as well (not pictured).

Comment: Have a look at using RxJS' distinct operator.

Comment: you can use union fron underscorejs: http://underscorejs.org/#union

Comment: @KetanAkbari - Any chance you could provide some type of example based on my scenario ?

Comment: you can also find find functions of underscorejs. first you can find similar object that you want to push if found then it will not push otherwise it will do.  you can see example in below  @Shailesh Ladumor answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this using RxJS' [**distinct**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinct.md) operator instead of manually checking for uniqueness yourself:

```
this._massEmpService.importedData
   .filter(obj => obj)
   .distinct(src => src.QID)
   .subscribe(obj => this.importResults.push(obj));
```

Comment: When I try this, I get an error that `src.QID` (my unique value) is undefined due to this subscribe function not yet having data. This subscribe call is wrapped in an `ngOnInit` so its trying to checked for data it doesn't have yet.

Comment: Really hard to diagnose your problem as there's not enough code in the snippet and how it's used in the template. Try adding a `filter` before the distinct.

Answer (score 2):

you can find first uoy object whatever you want push if not found then push it. for example

```
importResults: ImportResults[] = [];
import * as _ from 'lodash';
constructor(
    private _massEmpService: MassEmpService
) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribe to our subject that lets us know about the added employees
    this._massEmpService.importedData.subscribe(obj => {
        if (obj) {
            // Ensure that we have unique results in our imported data
            const keyExists= this._find((obj);
                if(keyExists){
                   this.importResults.push(obj);
                }
        }
    });
   }
```

create find function into component

```
  private _find(cur_obj: any): any{
                return _.find(this.importResults, function (importResult: any): boolean {
                   return importResult.QID === cur_obj.QID;
                });
 }
```

**this is example. you can change it based on your objects**

Comment: I tried to use this solution and the change I made was to the function to change my unique value to `QID`. `return importResult.QID === cur_obj.setting_key.QID;`. No errors occur but nothing is pushed to the `importResults` array as expected.

Comment: I also tried changing this to `if(!keyExists){` and when I try to push data after there is already a user, I get an error on this line `return importResult.QID === cur_obj.setting_key.QID;` saying that `QID` is undefined.

Comment: i have update answer based on your comment and check now

Comment: just remove setting_key from return importResult.QID === cur_obj.setting_key.QID;

Comment: you need to compare based on your object. i give you just example.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to remove the duplicates items in the array is by: 
Here I remove items that with duplicate names

```js
var myArray= [ { 'name': 'Mac'}, {'name': 'Mac'}, {'name': 'John'} ,{'name': 'Edward'}];

console.log('----------------Before removing-------------');
console.log(myArray);
 myArray.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (index !== myArray.findIndex(i => i.name === item.name)) {
                myArray.splice(index, 1);
            }
            
        });
console.log('---------------After removing------------------');
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the `importResults` variable every time the `subscription` runs. Just replace the `{}` in the `subscription()` with this:

```js
{
  if (obj) {
    this.importResults = [];
    // Ensure that we have unique results in our imported data
    this.importResults.push(_.uniqBy(obj, 'QID'));
  }
```

Comment: The issue is though, any records that have been selected will be reset correct? This component contains employee records with checkboxes next to them which allows them to pick ones they want to modify. From another component, they can add more employees to this list. If I am replacing the array each time, it will lose the state of any employees that are "checked". Due to this, I only wanted to push new data, not replace the whole thing.

Comment: You could copy the selected employee to a separate variable and use that instead. I use Lodash https://lodash.com/ to clone one variable to another. If you needed

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't really apply to all the object properties scenarios. I tried adding more properties to the array, and it didn't really remove the duplicacy.

```
var myArray= [ { 'name': 'Mac', 'id': '1', 'group_id': 66}, 
{'name': 'Mac', 'id': '2',  'group_id': 55},
{'name': 'John', 'id': '3',  'group_id': 66} ,
{'name': 'Edward', 'id': '4',  'group_id': 55}, 
{'name': 'Edward', 'id': '5',  'group_id': 70}];

console.log('----------------Before removing-------------');
console.log(myArray); myArray.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (index !== myArray.findIndex(i => i.group_id === item.group_id)) {
                myArray.splice(index+1, 1);
            }

        });
 console.log('---------------After removing------------------');
 console.log(myArray);
```

So I tried this code and this actually worked:

```
const data = [{name: 'AAA'}, {name: 'AAA'}, {name: 'BBB'}, {name: 'AAA'}];
function removeDuplicity(datas){
    return datas.filter((item, index,arr)=>{
    const c = arr.map(item=> item.name);
    return  index === c.indexOf(item.name)
  })`enter code here`
}

console.log(removeDuplicity(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code which worked for me.

1st example to identify whether array has duplicate object or not.

```
let hasDuplicate = false;
this.items.forEach((el) => {
            if (this.items.filter(x => x === el).length > 1) {
                this.hasDuplicate = true;
                return;
            }
        });
```

2nd example to get unique object from array.

```
let uniqueArr = [];
this.items.forEach((el) => {
            if (this.items.filter(x => x === el).length === 1) {
                this.uniqueArr.push(el);
            }
        });
```

I hope it will help someone.